# AWS, Express.js - Setting server to production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, production-environment

I'm developing my app locally and running on an EC2 instance on AWS. I'm wanting to differentiate between production and development and added this to my main.js file:

```
switch (app.settings.env) {
  case 'production':
    app.locals.base = 'example1.com';
    break;
  case 'development':
    app.locals.base = 'example2.com:8081';
    break;
  default:
}
```

Both my local and remote install of the app use development's declaration for `app.locals.base`. How can I "mark" my AWS instance as the production environment so that my app recognizes it?

**NOTE:** I tried adding this in my AWS Console

```
$ echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

And the contents of `.bash_profile`

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export NODE_ENV=production
```

Comment: You need to set the NODE_ENV when running node. For example, `NODE_ENV=development node index.js`.  Then you can check the NODE_ENV with `process.env.NODE_ENV`.  Heres an example: https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/judoka-resource/blob/master/index.js#L14-L26

Comment: there is a shell command called `ec2metadata`, use that to identify if that's ec2 instance or not. For example, if you run `ec2metadata ami-id` and get output, that's ec2 instance.